# ExcelLibrary and EPPlus throwing exceptions when opening network file

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel file on a server. I access it with a path looking like this : "\\Server\folder\file.xlsx".

I was able to read it with the Excel API from office, but since I cannot install office on my server, I need to avoid this dependency.

I tried using some other libraries, but it does not work...

I tried opening the file with EPPLUS, but I have an exception saying " This operation is not supported for a relative URI" when I try to open the workbook... I tried with ExcelLibrary, but I have an out of memory exception...

```
//EXCELLIBRARY
Workbook book = Workbook.Load(_filename);

//EPPLUS
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(_filename);
ExcelPackage pack = new ExcelPackage(file);
ExcelWorksheet sheet = pack.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
```

Does someone have an idea on how to solve this?

If not, you have another library to suggest? I don't want to use OleDB and already tried NOPI. I want a library that only need to add a reference to a dll. I need to open excel 2010 files. I also need to be able to determine what is the used range in the sheet and get a array with the values. Here is the code that I used and worked with the office API.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(_filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

 _range = (System.Array)xlWorkSheet.UsedRange.Value2;
 _headers = GetHeaders(_range);

 _lastRow = xlWorkSheet.Cells.Find("*", misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
 Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, misValue, misValue).Row;

 xlWorkBook.Close(false, misValue, misValue);
 xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching and trying many libraries all day, I finally found something that works, Koogra.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/koogra/?_test=b

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook(_filename);
_worksheet = wb.GetWorksheet(0);

//You can do the same to find LastCol, LastRow or FirstCol
uint firstRow = _worksheet.CellMap.FirstRow
string aHeader = (string)_worksheet.GetRow(firstRow).GetCell(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not what a network path looks like. It's supposed to be something like

```
\\server\path\to\file\image.jpg
```

Notice the double slashes at the beginning. With only one slash it becomes a path relative to the current drive (which is what the error is telling you).

Comment: Yes, it's like that. I wrote two slashes, but it displayed only one. I editied my post, I had to write three to display two...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that FileInfo constructor is throwing that exception, are you sure that EEPlus is throwing it ? Because on NT family FileInfo constructor is calling Path.NormalizeSlow and that method is throwing exception :

```
throw new ArgumentException(Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_PathUriFormatNotSupported"));
```

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure. The exception is thrown when I call pack.Workbook. I tried the exact same code with the library ExcelPackage (which is the starting point of EPPlus) and it works fine, but I didn't have the functions I needed to detect the last row or last column.

Answer (score 0):

Try with new Epplus library 4.1

Most of bugs are fixed in this version

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).